# Python 3.5 handling lists strangely

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across some rather strange behavior.

```
class Example:
    test = []

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.test)
        self.test.append(0)


ex1 = Example()
ex2 = Example()
ex3 = Example()
```

I'd expect this to output [] every time, however, I get:

```
[]
[0]
[0, 0]
```

What is this wizardry? Could you help me understand?
Thank, you!

Edit:
Hey, thank you for the quick answers.

Just to clarify, if "test" is static then why do I not notice this behavior when I replace "self.test.append(0)" with "self.test = [0]"?

Comment: `test` is a *class* attribute here, not an attribute of each *instance*. Don't try to "declare" members like this; you must create them in `__init__`.

Comment: `test` is a class variable, not an instance variable.  It is shared by all instances of your class. See, e.g., https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3.

Comment: «why do I not notice this behavior when I replace "self.test.append(0)" with "self.test = [0]"?» Because that binds a new object to the instance attribute `self.test`, and that will shadow the `Example.test` class attribute. Whereas doing `self.test.append(0)` merely mutates the existing object.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay, now I understand. Thank's!

Comment: BTW, please try to avoid modifying questions after they've already received valid answers. If you need additional clarification about an answer, do it in the comments of that answer, or ask a fresh question (possibly linking to the original question). Otherwise, you risk invalidating those answers & the answerers may not notice.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ok, good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is a static class attribute, which you are continually updating with values. Python is different from some other languages in this way. To make it an object attribute, use `self.test = []` in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`test` there is a [class-level static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python), which is shared between the instances of the class.

You'll want to initialize `test` within the `__init__` method.

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = []
        print(self.test)
        self.test.append(0)
```